# Engine temperature reading higher than usual

Tags: toyota, cooling-system, corolla

I have a 2011 Toyota Axio. Usually, the engine temperature gauge was always below the medium range. But recently I have noticed that it goes to the mid-level that is slightly higher than previously. What are some possible causes and what can I test to determine the problem?

Comment: Please post (or link) pictures showing where the coolant needle was previously and where it currently is. Also, what are the ambient operating conditions (ex. 10°C or 50°C)?

Answer (score 2):

Is it still within the safe range? It's probably safe to ignore at this point. Otherwise, check the coolant level and flush/replace if it's past your scheduled maintenance interval (check the manual). The internet tells me it should be changed at 160000km and every 80000km after that with a 50/50 mix of water and Toyota coolant (pink).

https://www.pakwheels.com/forums/t/fan-club-toyota-corolla-axio/217715/41

Answer (score 1):

Could be any number of things.  You don't mention if you changed any coolant lately.

- I would check your cooling fans.  I had one that would slow down, but not stop after running for a while and would cause the temperature to go up.
- Check for leaks and your coolant level. A small leak that is slowly lowering your coolant level could do this.
- Air in the coolant lines, usually after you change it and/or a thermostat.
- thermostat that is starting to go bad.